# set uniqueId(from header) to Winston logger when a client make an API request or refresh Winston params WITHOUT express

Tags: node.js, logging, header, global-variables, winston

I'm new in Node and I'm trying to use Winston to log my application.
Currently my App is serverless and I have exposed some REST APIs.
In my APIs, the client has the possibility to send in the headers a transactionRefId. The idea with this variable is to use it in all the modules, functions, etc that are involved in the API request, this will be useful to have a complete trace about what happens in the request.
I have a `logger.js` where I'm configuring Winston, just like this:

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, json, splat, timestamp } = format;
const logLevel = process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'info';
const logger = createLogger({
  level: logLevel,
  format: combine(timestamp(), splat(), json()),
  defaultMeta: { 
    service: 'my-service',
    'Transaction-Ref-Id': 'HERE SHOULD BE TXNREFID'},
  transports: [new transports.Console()],
  silent: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test',
});
module.exports = logger;
```

The idea is to set the `Transaction-Ref-Id` using the header, because the header has that Id. The problem I have is in my `logger.js` file I don't have access to the header because it runs before of the call of my API.
is there a way so overwrite my logger.js with the configuration of Winston and pass the transactionRefId or maybe extract the header or run my logger.js configuration after the header already exists?
I can't use express framework in my app. I only can work with Node.